# R: referencing a character string

Tags: r, function

Is it possible to feed R a character string and for it to know I'm looking for the data frame with that name?

**Example:**

```
    TestData <- matrix(1:100,nrow=10, ncol=10)
```

Then, if I want to reference it later, can I do something similar to this to have R pull dataset?

```
    paste("TestData$",x[1,],sep="")
```

When entered this way, it comes up as a character string and obviously returns no data. For context, I'm trying to do it this way because I'm creating a loop that goes through several data sets (and columns within those datasets), but does similar operations, so I would like to be able to dynamically change the referenced dataset.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Someone will eventually come along and tell you about `get()`, but tempting as that may seem, it is bad advice. Put the several data sets in a named list with generic names for each element. Then you can programmatically refer to the elements of the list by name or position and swap out data sets as needed.

Comment: did you try `get()`?